# Is #[account] relate at all to #[account(...)] or are they completely separate attributes?

Tags: anchor, account

Could someone clarify whether `#[account(...)]` used to apply constraints is completely different from `#[account]` used to specify the structure representing an account, or if they are related?

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64
}
```

Related pages from anchor-lang below:

https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/attr.account.html

https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.Accounts.html

Answer (score 1):

Both of these have different jobs to do `#[account]` is used to represent an on-chain data struct and implement's a bunch of functions on it for serialization and deserialization.

`#[account(...)]` on the other hand is used for validations + a bunch of stuff/attributes like init,mut,close, constraint in the derive macro struct where all the accounts for instructions are added.

I don't have a deep dive knowledge this answer is based of my experience using  anchor ;)